# handle ADIdentityNotFoundException without stopping the program

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have to loop for each object in an input file, doing a Get-ADUser on each object, and I want to handle the ADIdentityNotFoundException error without stopping the loop. Is there a better way I can accomplish this (simplified for example's sake):

```
Import-Csv $input | Foreach-Object {
    $manager = "BLANK"
    if ($user = Get-ADUser $_."samaccountname" -properties * ) {

        # I don't think I need this in an IF{} since the line below won't work
        # so $manager will be equal to the last value set, "BLANK", but
        # this makes it easier to understand what I want to happen

        $manager = $user."manager"

        # I need more properties (thus -properties *) but again just an example
    }

}
```

In essence, if the Get-ADUser lookup is successful, set `$manager = $user."manager"`

If it is not successful, do not stop the loop, do not copy the value of the previous user, have `$manager = "BLANK"`(or whatever). The issue I have with the try/catch solutions, is that `ADIdentityNotFoundException` doesn't trigger the catch unless I add `-ErrorAction Stop`, which will cause the undesired result of the program terminating.

Comment: please _carefully read the `try/catch/finally` structure documentation_. it is designed to give you specific control over how to handle errors - a terminating error **_in the try block_** will  trigger the `catch` block - it won't terminate the program..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your program would be terminating. Using the below sample code loops through all the users in the array. I have purposely entered an incorrect username into the second value of the array (position [1]):

```
$users = "username1", "username2", "username3" #username2 is purposely incorrect
foreach ($i in $users){
    try{
        $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $i -Properties * -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Found"
    }catch{
        Write-Host "Not found"
    }
}
```

my output is

> found
>
> not found
>
> found